# There is a way to redirect to another page in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

There is a way to redirect from a page to another page inside a OrchestrationStep?

E.g: When user reaches end of page, has a CTA Button, when someone click, It is expected redirect to anoher page (via Javascript), has a way?

[image: end before redirect]

**Note: I tried redirect only using location.assign(href) and when it try redirect, redirects to endpoint jwt.ms

Answer (score 5):

The way that I had chosen was to use an OpenID Connect technical profile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile

Example:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SignUpOrSignIn-OIDC-Redirect">
  <DisplayName>Redirect to a different site</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.google.com</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id">RequiredButDoesntMatter</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```